# jQuery usage of delegate causes events to fire for each element (2 4 8 16 32)

Tags: delegates, jquery

So I wrote the code below:

```
   jQuery('#contentWrapper').delegate(".addButton", "click", function(){
      addRow(jQuery(this));
   });

function addRow(thisButton){

        var parent = thisButton.parent();  
        console.log("parent = ",parent);

        var childrenNoEvents = thisButton.parent().children().clone(false); 
        console.log("childrenClone = ",childrenNoEvents);

        var cloneWithoutEvents = thisButton.parent().clone(false);
        console.log("parentClone = ",cloneWithoutEvents);

        thisButton.parent().append(childrenNoEvents);
    };
```

which operates on an DOM element like this

```
<div class="whatever">
    <span>first element</span><span class="addButton">O</span><span class="deleteButton">X</span>
</div>
```

When I click the O(the DOM element with the addButton class) the first time it works properly, but subsequent times it creates/clones twice as many elements as the prior click. I assume it has to do with the delegate handler calling addRow for as many ".addButton" classes there are in the DOM but I don't know how to fix it.

Bonus Question:

How would I use a closure to create a persistent variable that I can increment inside the addRow function each time the event is fired? (or is there a better way to do that?)

Comment: I don't see how it works at all. You try to append `children` but you haven't created it. You sure that matches your code? Also, you clone the children and the parents and then don't do anything with them. Finally, why save `thisButton.parent()` into a variable and then not use it when you next need the parent?

Comment: sorry this was a formatting error from when I was editing the code to be as clear as possible for this question. Also, that variable and log functions you mention were remnants of me trying figure out what was going on. I have fixed the first error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you execute the function, you copy the contents of .whatever back into .whatever, effectively doubling them. Try using this approach:

```
$('#contentWrapper').on("click", ".addButton", function() { // note that I use the .on() function, as .delegate() is just a wrapper since jQuery 1.7
    addRow($(this));
});

function addRow(thisButton){
    thisButton.closest('ul').append(thisButton.parent().clone(false));
};
```

With HTML syntax like this:

```
<div id="contentWrapper">
    <ul class="whatever">
        <li>
            <span>first element</span>
            <span class="addButton">O</span>
            <span class="deleteButton">X</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can test it with this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZsCCs/

More info about the .on() method: http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html

Comment: Thank you very much, I am still learning to think in dynamic jQuery and this will forever stay in my head as a lesson for debugging this stuff. To make sure I understood what I was doing incorrectly I came up with an alternate solution that applies the lesson you taught here:

Comment: And that solutions is:               thisButton.parent().clone().insertAfter(thisButton.parent());

Comment: Yep, also very nice use of chaining ;)